# visual studio 2015 installation blocked

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I try to install Visual Studio 2015, for several days...
I made several unsuccessful searches... I try to uninstall any older versions. I hang on this screen:
[.net framework installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omdjt.png)
I see nothing in the logs. I really do not understand what is happening. If someone an idea?

Comment: Could you translate the error message in your screenshot to the English? And use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder. Please upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.

Comment: A translation  :  "Microsoft .net framework required for the installation of Visual Studio 2015 Entreprise with"  Companythe link for the vslog.zip here https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnFJrA-K1hKWunu3IVHyHlfiN8Go. thanks

Comment: go to Control Panel—Programs and Features—Turn Windows features on or off and disable .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) and re-run the VS installer, if it is already disabled, you can try to enable it and re-run the VS installer.

Comment: thanks s09. it's ok now;

Comment: @Didou000 did you fixed it using my workaround? If not, could share your solution, it will help others community members to search a workaround.

Comment: @s09 your workaroud was the solution for my problem. I don t know how to propose your answer as a solution. (Thks again ! 3 days frustrate before your help)

Comment: @Didou000 since it need 50 reputations to add a comment and my account not achieved it yet, so I ask for help from my friend to help me add it, I already added the answer with my own account, could you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s09: Go to Control Panel—Programs and Features—Turn Windows features on or off and disable .NET Framework 3.5 (includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) and re-run the VS installer, if it is already disabled, you can try to enable it and re-run the VS installer.